# Can't figure out the correct way to implement if statement on dataframe with apply lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a simple dataframe (df) with two columns (Name and Value). I want to add a third column (New Value) based on Name.

I have tried:

```
df['New Value'] = df[['Name ']].apply((lambda x: df['Value'] * 2 if x == 'John' else df['Value']) , axis=0)
```

By doing this I get the following error:

ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index Name')

What I understand is that x is a Series and I cannot compare to a string, is this correct? If not, what does it mean?

In any case, how do I go around this problem?

Comment: you should replace `df[Value]' by x['value']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the operation on a dataframe of column only `'Name'` and when working with row wise operation, set `axis=1`

Try this for your usecase.

```py
df['New Value'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Value'] * 2 if x['Name'] == 'John' else x['Value'], axis=1)
```

Solution

```py
In [49]: df
Out[49]:
    Name  Value
0   John      5
1  Kevin      5

In [50]: df['New Value'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Value'] * 2 if x['Name'] == 'John' else x['Value'], axis=1)

In [51]: df
Out[51]:
    Name  Value  New Value
0   John      5         10
1  Kevin      5          5
```

Comment: Both answers work fine. I'll use the one that best suits to my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to do this:

```
df['New Value'] = (df['Value'] * 2).where(df['Name'] == 'John',  df['Value'])
```

Comment: Does where allow me to use more than one condition?

Comment: @teoeme139 You can stack conditions with the logical operators: `~(df.Name == 'John') | (df.Horse == 'Bountiful Leap')`. Be sure to use parentheses to propagate the conversions to Series to propagate.

Comment: @teoeme139 or use .isin so, `df.Name.isin(["John", "Mike"])`